# Where is the "Touch" command in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 3.x, if I changed a resource file I could right-click it and select touch to ensure that it would be included in the next build.

I don't see that in Xcode 4. Has it been removed?

Answer (score 1):

The community discovered it was gone in early Xcode 4 preview builds. It stayed gone when Xcode 4 was released. File a bug report to request it be added back in.

Comment: [Filed a bug (#14219655)](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/55/wo/XWiOEzCsVVA3uttuCc0Veg/7.66)... not sure if it is a dupe or not, but hey, it's worth a shot.